# How to get the icon from a handler execute method in eclipse e4

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

Using a handler for a menu contribution I can get the ParameterizedCommand in the execute method as below.

```
@Execute
public void execute(final Event event, final ParameterizedCommand command)
```

How can I get the iconURI of the selected menu item?

I tried this but get "Discouraged Access" warnings

```
final MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem) event.widget;
    Object obj = (Object) menuItem.getData("modelElement");
    HandledMenuItemImpl item = (HandledMenuItemImpl) obj;
    String iconUrl = item.getIconURI();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just inject the `MMenuItem` to the handler:

```
@Execute
public void execute(MMenuItem menuItem, ..... other parameters)
{
   String iconUrl = menuItem.getIconURI();
   ...
}
```

If the handler is also called from non-menu events make the menu item optional

```
@Execute
public void execute(@Optional MMenuItem menuItem, ..... other parameters)
{
   if (menuItem != null) {
      String iconUrl = menuItem.getIconURI();
      ...
   }
}
```